# Deploy Ethereum network in several machines

Tags: ethereum, geth

After my first approach deploying an Ethereum network with `testrpc`, I´m wondering if I can deploy several nodes using docker containers, so I can deploy a real network with several machines/nodes, and I have some questions:

¿Can I use `testrpc` for this this task or I need to use `Geth` instead? Because reading the docs I think `testrpc` is too basic for it

¿Does Truffle or another framework help you to do all this stuff?

Any information related with all this is welcomed because, as I said, I´m in a very initial stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestRPC is just a tool that will simulate an Ethereum network. Nothing else.

If you want to create an ethereum network you'll have to use an ethereum client like Geth, deploy it on various machines in order to makes those machines nodes.

If you want to be a separate network you'll have to change some parameters before launching your client.

I'll leave here some documentation that explains it : [See the doc](https://medium.com/mercuryprotocol/how-to-create-your-own-private-ethereum-blockchain-dad6af82fc9f)